# "Windows Resume Loader" screen is stuck trying to boot up after sleep/hibernation

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I can't remember if I put my machine to hibernate or sleep, but I'm going to assume hibernation. The keyboard works just (in BIOS) fine until it gets to the screen it's sitting at now is titled, "Windows Resume Loader":

> The last attempt to resume the system
>   from its previous location failed.
>   Attempt to resume again? (Use the
>   arrow keys to highligh your choice.)
>
> Continue with system resume
>
> Delete restoration data and proceed to system boot menu

I've tried resetting BIOS with no luck.

Any help would be great. I don't want to format!

Comment: After way more digging around, I found this article, and basically I have to enable the USB Keyboard, it was disabled for some reason, even though I could still get to and navigate around BIOS: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/36407a58-e66b-43de-a21d-f118c85153b4

Answer (score 1):

You can try follwing things.

> > Boot windows with Last Known Good Configuration. 
> >     Start windows with command promot and run chkdsk utility. that will some resolve disk issue if there is.

Still if you face any issue you should start windows in safe mode and and restore windows to earlier date.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try and boot with "Last Known Good Configuration" and Windows wouldn't even let me get to start in Safe Mode with F8, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernation file is screwed. Using any bootable CD which gives you access to the Windows file system, delete the hibernation file and reboot. I can't imagine why your'e playing around with the BIOS for a simple Windows error.

Comment: Deleting the hibernation file was the next step since I was making a Win7 bootable USB on my laptop (I haven't yet installed my optical drive). Simple Windows error that makes a user manually remove a hibernate file? Not so simple. BIOS worked just fine, thanks.